# How would one do to make a function that returns the closest coordinates to the input I have in a list using Pythagoras?? Python

Tags: python

The Problem:

I need to create a function that takes 3 parameters where 2 of the parameters are numbers. for example `def find_closest(ph,x,y)` where ph is a list containing dictionaries. the function is supposed to look through the list of dictionaries and return the closest x and y value to the ones I put in the parameters.

For example if I have a list containing following dictionaries `[{'x': 100, 'y': 305, 'name': 'David'}, {'x': 100, 'y': 302, 'name': 'Lukas'}]` and used the the `find_closest` function  with the following arguments find_closest`(ph,100,300)` the function should return `100,302` . Now how am I supposed to solve this problem with Pythagoras theorem?

Comment: I assume it would take some code. Have you tried anything to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A simple solution with a `for-loop`:

```
def find_closest(ph, x, y):
   closestDif = float('inf')
   for d in ph:
      if abs((d['x'] + d['y']) - (x + y)) < closestDif:
         closestDif = abs((d['x'] + d['y']) - (x + y))
         closest = d
   return closest
```

This `function` works by looping through each dictionary `(d)` in `ph` and if the `x` attribute of that dictionary plus the `y` attribute - the sum of the two inputs (all absoluted i.e. made positive) is less than the smallest difference found so far `(closestDif)`, then make the `closestDif` be that value and record the `dictionary` that is the closest so far in the variable `closest`. Finally `return` the closest `dictionary` at the end.

...with your input of:

```
find_closest([{'x': 100, 'y': 305, 'name': 'David'}, {'x': 100, 'y': 302, 'name': 'Lukas'}], 100, 300)
```

we get the output you wanted of:

```
{'y': 302, 'x': 100, 'name': 'Lukas'}
```

hope this does the job! :)

### Another method using pythagoras:

Using the formula:

```
((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y2)^2)^0.5
```

we can work out the distances more accurately and escape any weird errors that the above method might encounter.

One **key thing** to note is that we **don't** need to take the square root when comparing them. This is due to the fact that taking the sqrt only scales the answer so is not necessary for comparisons between the different `dictionaries`.

This means we can re-write the above `function` using `pythagoras`:

```
def find_closest(ph, x, y):
   closestDif = float('inf')
   for d in ph:
      if (x - d['x']) ** 2 + (y - d['y']) ** 2 < closestDif:
         closestDif = (x - d['x']) ** 2 + (y - d['y']) ** 2
         closest = d
   return closest
```

which produces the expected result as above.

Comment: Only suggestion I'd make is to change the initial value of `closestDif` to None, then in your if-statement, add an `or` to see if closestDif is None. That way, if the closest difference in the dictionaries is actually > 10000, it won't report the wrong result.

Comment: @ChrisForrence yes I have updated the code now to `initialise` it as infinity :) to save the extra check in the loop

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the distance you're trying to calculate, let's assume it's the Cartesian distance between two points:

```
def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return ((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)**.5

def find_closest(ph,x,y):
    m = distance(x, y, ph[0]['x'], ph[0]['y'])
    c = ph[0]
    for i in range(1, len(ph)):
      d = distance(x, y, ph[i]['x'], ph[i]['y'])
      if d<m:
        m=d
        c=ph[i]
    return (c['x'], c['y'])

arr = [{'x': 100, 'y': 305, 'name': 'David'}, {'x': 100, 'y': 302, 'name': 'Lukas'}]
result = find_closest(arr,100,300)
print(result) # => (100, 302)
```